# Why does my superclass object call its subclass method?

Tags: objective-c, stanford-nlp

I have seen so many helpful threads here, but this is my first time posting!

I was working on the infamous Stanford OpenCourse project: Matchismo. While I got everything going just fine, but I don't understand one part of the sample codes.

Basically the code below is used to get a Card object to compare with another card.

```
- (void) flipCardAtIndex: (NSUInteger)index
{
    Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];
    if (card && !card.isUnplayable)
    {
        if (!card.isFaceUp)
        {
            for (Card* otherCard in self.cards)//for-in loop
            {
                if (otherCard.isFaceUp && !otherCard.isUnplayable)
                {
                    int matchScore = [card match:@[otherCard]];
......
```

And this is how cardAtIndex works:

```
-(Card *) cardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index < [self.cards count])
        //dot notation is used for property
        //[] is used for method
    {
        return self.cards[index];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here are the methods for Match(card*) and Match(playingCard)

Match(card*)

```
-(int) match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
    NSLog(@"here");
    int score = 0;

    for (Card *card in otherCards)
    {
        if ([card.content isEqualToString:self.content])
            score = 1;
        {
            NSLog(@"Card Match");
        }

    }
    return score;
}
```

Match(PlayingCard*)

```
-(int) match: (NSArray *)otherCards;
{
    int score = 0;
    if ([otherCards count] == 1)
    {
        PlayingCard *otherCard = [otherCards lastObject];//the last object in the array
        if ([otherCard.suit isEqualToString:self.suit])
            score = 1;
        else if (otherCard.rank == self.rank)
            score = 4;
        NSLog(@"PlayingCard Match");
    }
    return score; 
}
```

It worked just fine, but I don't get why when a Card* object calls a method, its subclass's PlayingCard's method is invoked.
Thanks so much for help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept is called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

It allows you to have a base class which provides some interface, and a set of subclasses that implement these methods in some different ways. The classic example is a `Drawable` class method `draw`, and its subclasses `Circle` and `Rectangle`, that both override the `draw` method to render themselves in some specific manner.

So goes for your `Card` base class, it calls its own interface method `match`, but as an object is actually not an instance of `Card`, but of a `PlayingCard` subclass, subclass method gets called instead to provide specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that the instance should be of a PlayingCard subclass, but I am not sure how it is generated. When I created the instance, it is of a PlayingCard subclass, but as I called a method to take it as an argument and return a Card class result, I don't understand why it is still a instance variable of PlayingCard Method

Comment: Look closely at `cardAtIndex:` method - it doesn't create a `Card` instance, instead it returns something complying to `Card` interface, and its implementation simply returns one of `self.cards`, each of them is a `PlayingCard`. Why doesn't it get "casted" to a `Card` type? Well, in some languages it could, but in Objective-C, like in many dynamically typed languages, all methods are polymorphic by default. (Compare with C++, where casting to `Card` will actually call `Card` methods unless you declare them explicitly as `virtual`, e.g. polymorphic).

Comment: Great explanation. Now I understand why. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller .m file, the property "deck" must be initialized as class PlayingCardDeck, and in PlayingCardDeck.m, the class of card is PalyingCard. So even though you declared your card as class Card, the method it calls will still be the one in class PlayingCard.